# Can I use half-seconds when linking to a specific point in a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I know that it's possible to [link to a specific point](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/732/60818) in a YouTube video by adding `#t=XhYmZs` to the end of the URL. (i.e. [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zA1jRmAYfU#t=1h2m48s`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zA1jRmAYfU#t=1h2m48s)). However, sometimes I want be a bit more specific so the video doesn't start playing mid-sentence.

Is it possible to use a more specific timestamp? Can I send a link that starts 48.5 seconds into a video? (i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuCn8ux2gbs&t=48.5s`)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible on Youtube right now.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94545/starting-a-youtube-video-in-the-middle-of-a-second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#start) with added emphrasis

> `start`
>
> This parameter causes the player to begin playing the video at the given number of seconds from the start of the video. **The parameter value is a positive integer.** Note that similar to the seekTo function, the player will look for the closest keyframe to the time you specify. This means that sometimes the play head may seek to just before the requested time, usually no more than around two seconds.

In other words:

- No, you cannot specify half-seconds as-is.
- Even if you could, the distance between keyframes is the limiting factor for precise linking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reply and stuff, so I'll post an answer and see how much abuse I get.  There seems to be much less hate over here than in the category I usually read.
@Leo Wattenberg touches on the closely related question that brought me here: Is there no switch/modifier (or similar but separate function) that allows the use of frames or keyframes as an argument?
And that seems to confirm my suspicion from research: no.
But it looks like I misunderstood seekTo, and using that with doubles instead of integers might, by luck, get me a more preferable keyframe than integers.  My competence in this area doesn't extend beyond the "just add some characters to the URL I found" approach that @Stevoisiak and I were using ([This link](http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/sq2dV/1/) from a relevant question is over my head, at least for today) but this is a huge step in my quest to play a clip from a 40s Disney movie at a slightly more convenient moment.

Edit: I guess I'm posting more of a solution than I thought, so posting this as an answer is almost appropriate?